# How can I correctly represent a box structure with dotted pairs in Lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, lispworks

I have issue with representing box structure via LISP's dotted pairs.

```
CL-USER 21 > (cons 1 (cons (cons 3 4) (cons (cons 3 4) 2)))

(1 (3 . 4) (3 . 4) . 2)
```

This is what i have, this is the output, but that's clearly incorrect, because the 3.4 pair is there twice, can someone help me correct this please? It has to be represented with cons(dotted pairs).[image]

ive tried to represent it many different ways, but i cant find the solution for this.

Comment: Related: to draw in ascii, see [draw-cons-tree](https://github.com/phoe-trash/draw-cons-tree).

Answer (score 5):

You can create it like this:

```
CL-USER 1 > (let ((c (cons 3 4)))
              (cons 1
                    (cons c
                          (cons c 2))))
(1 (3 . 4) (3 . 4) . 2)
```

We don't see it in the printed output, but the sublists are the same object:

```
CL-USER 2 >  (eq (second *) (third *))
T
```

We can let Lisp make the structure clear:

```
CL-USER 3 > setf *print-circle* t
T

CL-USER 4 > ***
(1 #1=(3 . 4) #1# . 2)
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a variable so you can refer to the same pair in multiple places.

```
(let ((box34 (cons 3 4)))
  (cons 1 (cons box34 (cons box34 2))))
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to declare a specific variable to compose your list, you just need to use the [Sharpsign Sharpsign](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/02_dhp.htm) :

```
CL-USER> (setf foo '(1 #1=(3 . 4) #1# . 2))
(1 (3 . 4) (3 . 4) . 2)

CL-USER> (eq (second foo) (third foo))
T
```

Answer (score 2):

[This is really a comment not an answer, but it's too long for a comment.]

As you are using LispWorks, you might be interested in using its grapher as a visualisation tool to see cons trees.  Here is a function which will do that:

```
(use-package :capi)

(defun show-cons-graph (c)
  (contain
   (make-instance 'graph-pane
                  :roots (list c)
                  :children-function (lambda (c)
                                       (typecase c
                                         (cons (list (car c) (cdr c)))
                                         (t '())))
                  :print-function (lambda (c)
                                    (typecase c
                                      (cons "")
                                      (t (format nil "~S" c)))))))
```

Here is

```
(show-cons-graph (cons 1 (cons (cons 3 4) (cons (cons 3 4) 2)))
```

[image: not sharing]

and here is

```
(let ((c (cons 3 4)))
  (show-cons-graph (cons 1 (cons c (cons c 2)))))
```

[image: sharing]